# Sorting date column by DD/MM/YYY in jQuery DataTables 1.10.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, date, datatable

I am using DataTables to display some MySQL data that contains a date column.

All date data in my table is displayed in the DD/MM/YYYY format, and no matter many different things I try, I cannot get it to sort in any other way than by the first two numbers.

I am currently using this method of sorting as I think it suits my data best:

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-uk

```
"columns": [
        { "data": "Address" },
        { "data": "Date_seen", "type" : "date-uk" },
```

I have also tried to sort using this method, more like the example on the DataTables website:

```
"columnDefs": [
      { "type": "date-uk", "targets": 1 }
    ],
```

I have tried copying in the plug-in code to my JavaScript file, and have also tried referencing the plug-in via the DataTables CDN.

I realise there are a lot of similar questions but they all seem to be relevant to older versions of DataTables from a few years ago, and contain the use of older initialisations such as `sType`, `aaSorting` and `aoColumns`.

I hope someone can shed some light on why this isn't working, it's driving me mad!

Comment: not sure why the code shown in link isn't working for you. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that includes your attempt. Can use CDN resources for plugin and css code.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I can't put my attempt into jsfiddle as I'm working on a healthcare system containing sensitive patient information, and the MySQL database is only being hosted locally on my machine at the moment while I test. Would it be helpful to see more of my javascript file? Just to test the date sorting on a smaller scale, I have made a jsfiddle with made up information and it runs without issue... http://jsfiddle.net/mikethirteen/k9rm3qL6/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I haven't found out why using the above plugin isn't working for me, I have implemented a workaround which serves as an answer to this issue in my case.

DataTables handles dates using YYYY-MM-DD by default, so I created a second date column where the data is formatted in this way. I also use a javascript function to update the column in this format when the original one is changed.

Using the DataTables option `iDataSort` on my original column, and by hiding this new 'default date' column using `bVisible`, I am now displaying my original column but sorting it using the hidden 'default date' column. Below is an example of how I am initialising this workaround.

> ```
> "columns": [
>       { "data": "Name_of_Patient", "width" : "10%" },
>       { "data": "Address" },
>       { "data": "Hospital_Number" },
>       { "data": "PCT" },
>       { "data": "Date_of_Pres", "iDataSort" : 5 },
>       { "data": "Date_of_Pres_Sort", "bVisible" : false }
> ],
> ```

Comment: @mikethirteen, I am having the same issue as you, however, the difference is that I am 1.) using server side processing and 2.) my date values are formatted server side. I tried using your solution but it's not working for me, so I would just like to find out if you are using server side processing and server side formatted values as well ?